# Why use a combination of ($E$, $H$) to describe electromagnetic systems instead of ($E$, $B$) or ($D$, $H$)?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, conventions

I attended a lecture on theoretical electrodynamics, and there we exclusively used the combination of **E** and **B** to fundamentally describe electromagnetism. They contain no approximation for material behaviour and use the exact charge density and current density (including the bound charges and bound currents in materials).

In the very last lecture we introduced the concept of looking at the system macroscopically, approximating the bound charges and currents in the material as Polarisations **P** and Magnetizations **M** and "absorbing them" into the new **D** and **H** Field.

**D** and **H** thus present an easy way to write the Maxwell equations just for the external charges and currents, where we don't have to precicely know all the the internal ones.

So to my understanding you had these to combinations: You either had to describe the system fully with the combination of (**E**, **B**), or you could use the combo (**D**, **H**) to factor out bound microscropic charges and currents.

Why then, when I look in many engineering books now, do they use a combination of (**E**, **H**) to describe their systems? Why this mishmash of macroscopic framework **H** and microscopic one **E**? Why use **H** where the microscopic processes are factored out, but then also **E** where they are not?

Comment: One thing to note is that $D$ and $B$ are flux densities (you  integrate them over areas) and $E$ and $H$ are intensities (you integrate them over paths).   Maxwell's equations written in the language of differential forms makes this manifest:  $D$ and $B$ are 2-forms, $E$ and $H$ are 1-forms. This gives some weight to using the mixed fields.

Comment: @garyp interesting! I'm not sure if these engineering books really considered differential forms to make the choice to use $E$ and $H$, but this _does_ give a mathematical motivation for it. Thank you.

Comment: @garyp That's an interesting comment. Since space is 3d, one-forms and two-forms can be interchanged with no ambiguity, so we could just as well use a two-form to represent $\mathbf{E}$, for example. (Not recommended, but possible.) But that breaks down when we consider the generalization to $D$-dimensional space. For example, when $D=2$, the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ has only one component (because it's a two-form), but a one-form has two components. So if $\mathbf{H}$ is a one-form, where does its extra component come from?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly In the formulation in terms of differential forms, I don't believe that the $E$ and $B$ fields are considered fundamental objects. Instead, you would always consider the field strength 2-form (in special relativity the Faraday tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$). I think that in 3+1 dimensions the constitutive form $G$ is also a 2-form, and maybe this isn't the case in 2+1 dimensions.

Comment: @MatthewO'Brien Yeah, that's where I'm coming from, except that I was splitting $F_{\mu\nu}$ into time-space and space-space parts and only using forms for the space parts: $F_{0k}dx^k$ and $F_{jk}dx^j\wedge dx^k$. Seems like the constitutive form $G$ should follow the same pattern as $F$, in any number of dimensions. In particular, the magnetic part should be a two-form, whether it's $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{H}$. Treating $\mathbf{H}$ is a one-form in $3+1$ dimensions seems unnatural, but I don't have an engineering background, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Looking at the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Linear_macroscopic_influence_of_matter) I can see that the constitutive form is defined in terms of the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijkl}$. In 3+1 dimensions $\epsilon$ has 4 indices, but in 2+1 only has 3. It should be possible to write it out in component form (*gasp*) to find $\mathbf{H}$ in terms of $F_{\mu\nu}$, but I have no physical intuition about what this would mean.

Answer (score 5):

I was confused by this too when I first encountered it. After all, $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are the "real" fields (in the sense that they directly determine the force experienced by a charge) - so they seem like the natural pair. When I first studied electromagnetic waves in university, everything was in terms of $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$, with little mention of $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. $\mathbf{H}$ also showed up a lot when we learnt about transformers, but in that case $\mathbf{B}$ showed up just as much.

[Griffiths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Electrodynamics) gives an explanation along these lines:

The pair $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ are commonly seen together because they are easy to measure. In the low-frequency limit:

- The line integral of $\mathbf{E}$ gives voltage between the endpoints of the path. Voltages are easily measured with a voltmeter.
- The loop integral of $\mathbf{H}$ gives the (free) current passing through the loop. Free currents are easily measured with an ammeter.

This is only true in the low-frequency limit, since otherwise there are "coupling" terms $\partial\mathbf{B}/\partial t$ and $\partial\mathbf{D}/\partial t$ which will affect the line integrals of $\mathbf{E}$ and the loop integrals of $\mathbf{H}$. Griffiths goes on to say that if it was more natural to measure build-ups of (free) charge than voltage, then we would be seeing $\mathbf{D}$ a lot more often.

Another reason for choosing the pair $(\mathbf{E},\mathbf{H})$ is that it gives a nice form for the Poynting vector, which (in the time domain) is:
$$\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{H}$$
This corresponds nicely to the formula for power from circuit theory:
$$P=IV$$
Expressing the Poynting vector in terms of other pairs of fields would cause additional constant factors to appear out the front (although technically you could use different units to make these constant factors into 1). Apparently there has been [some debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector#Definition) in the past about which form of the Poynting vector should be preferred.

Also note that the usual units of $\mathbf{E}$ are volts per meter (voltage per unit length), and the usual units of $\mathbf{H}$ are amps per meter (current per unit length) - which gives a very nice watts per meter squared for the Poynting vector! So it's as if $\mathbf{E}$ is "voltage-like" and $\mathbf{H}$ is "(free) current-like", which gives nice results for the Poynting vector, for units, and nice relationships to real-world measurements.

**Caveat**

Griffith warns the reader against thinking of $\mathbf{H}$ as determined only by the free current distribution and somehow "factoring out" the effects of magnetic media. This is a natural conclusion to reach, since in magnetostatics we have $\nabla\times\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{J}_\mathrm{f}$, which is similar to $\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\mathbf{J}$ that gives rise to the Biot-Savart law. However, *unlike* $\mathbf{B}$, $\mathbf{H}$ does not necessarily have zero divergence, instead we have:
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{H}=-\nabla\cdot\mathbf{M}$$
Which means that $\mathbf{H}$ also depends on the magnetization of the medium. However, *loop integrals of* $\mathbf{H}$ will always be equal to the free current passing through the loop (in magnetostatics at least, since otherwise the displacement current term $\partial\mathbf{D}/\partial t$ will be non-negligible).

Answer (score 3):

Physics is littered with various notational conventions. Generally people will use whatever combination of variables and whatever system of units they find most convenient at the time for their purpose. In electrodynamics one would generally use whatever combination of variables which makes Maxwell's equations "look the simplest" given the presence of sources, bound currents/charges, etc. I know of no reason other than pure convenience.

Any formulation of Maxwell's equations in terms of $(E,H)$ or $(E,B)$ or $(D,H)$ is formally equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If my memory is correct, this is because they are the easiest (or most common) to measure.

Comment: I think I also remember reading this explanation somewhere once...

I'm not sure why $H$ would be more straightforward to measure than $B$, but I think such an explanation would be more fitting for an engineering textbook than considering differential forms.

Comment: I think taking the units into account with common tools can give insight into that. Theory is usually applied at some point.

Comment: You've reminded me of my undergrad lab classes! The Wiki page "magnetic field" points out that a measurement device such as a magnetic field probe will typically generate its own magnetic field in response to the external applied field. So in this case, the $H$ field is in fact more directly accessible experimentally and is the more convenient variable.

Answer (score 1):

**History**
There is a long history of using fields $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ together, which is reflected in their names and notations: $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ are sometimes called *tensions*, while $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are called *displacements/inductions* (I am not sure how generally accepted these terms are in English, but other languages do make this distinction). This is further reflected, e.g., in the form of the constitutive relations:
$$
\mathbf{D}=\varepsilon\mathbf{E}, \mathbf{B}=\mu\mathbf{H}
$$
(rather than $\mathbf{H}=\mu\mathbf{B}$).

**Macroscopic electrodynamics**
When dealing with macroscopic Maxwell equations, any pair of electric and magnetic fields can be used without causing ambiguity:
$$
\mathbf{E}\text{ and }\mathbf{H}\\
\mathbf{E}\text{ and }\mathbf{B}\\
\mathbf{D}\text{ and }\mathbf{H}\\
\mathbf{D}\text{ and }\mathbf{B}
$$

**Miscroscopic electrodynamics**
In microscopic electrodynamics the distinction between the tensions and the induced fields disappears. In Gaussian units they are simply equal:
$$
\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{E},\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{H},
$$
so again the use of specific letters is a matter of convention in a particular field.